# Android OpenGL ES texture animation

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a game for android and this is my first experience with OpenGL.
When the application loads I create my vertices and texture buffers, I load images from drawable resources; using GLUtils.tex2Image2D to bind the image to a texture array.

I was wondering if glBindTexture() was the correct function to use when changing the texture to produce animation.

```
public void onDraw(GL10 gl){
    sprite.animate();
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[sprite.frameNumber]);
    sprite.draw(gl);
}
```

### Code Explanation

*sprite.animate()* - changes the frame number depending on System.uptimeMillis()

*sprite.draw()* - does the actual drawing:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

//Disable the client state before leaving
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

The function does work, but I wanted to confirm it was the correct function to use, or if there is an alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding a different texture to animate is one way to do what you want.

A more popular way of doing this is to have all your animations frames in a big texture (pack all the individual frames in a huge rectangle): to draw a different frame, just change the texture coordinates.

For example, pack four frames of animation in a big 2x2 square

```
1|2
3|4
```

Then you'll use for texture coordinates (0,0) (0.5,0) (0.5,0.5) (0,0.5) to display frame 1, and the rest should be obvious.

Comment: Am I right to assume I need multiple texture byteBuffers? To be used on my draw function with gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer); before calling gl.glDrawArrays();

Comment: Yes, you will need to use multiple texture coordinates buffers. What you can also do is to create bigger buffers with all the texture coordinates, and specify which ones to use by changing the second argument (the "first" point to use) in gl.glDrawArrays(). Note that you will need to duplicate your vertex information for that to work.

Comment: What if I'm generating mipmaps for textures? I think that on low-sized mipamps (like 1x1 or 2x2) different frames can mix together. And `glGenerateMipMap()` function doesn't have parameter specifying minimum mipmap size.